# How can I position tickmarks and axis labels (or ticktext) at the end of bars (rather than centered) in a bar chart using R plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart, axis-labels, xticks

I am trying to create a bar chart that shows how much funds received households of certain income. For that I am using the following code:

```
chart <- plot_ly(funds,
                  x = ~income_group, 
                  y = ~FundsSent, 
                  type = "bar")

chart <- chart %>% layout(title = '<b>Fund Distribution by Income</b>',
                            xaxis = list(
                              title = list(text='Income', standoff = 10), 
                              ticks="outside", tickson="boundaries"),
                            yaxis = list(
                              title = list(text='Funds paid', standoff = 10)),
                            bargap = 0.05)
```

Now, with `"tickson=boundaries"` I managed to get the tickmarks at the end of every bar (rather than centered), but the labels are still in the middle of the column.

[Bar chart showing missplacement of axis labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvpqD.png)

This tells the wrong story, as it would appear that the first column for example shows the funds paid to those with 0 income, when instead it's showing the funds paid to those with income 0 to 5,000.

I have also tried setting the X axis labels by hand, using `tickmode="array"`, `ticktext` and setting `tickvals` manually but, while that aligns the ticks with the text, it goes again to centering the tickmarks (as if the `tickson="boundaries"` argument wasn't working anymore).

Any help for a desperate and frustrated economist?

Comment: When I use your code, the tickmarks are still centered on bars, even with `tickson="boundaries"`. Can you include data using `dput()` so that your example is reproducible (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just made it work using `tickson="boundaries"` to set the ticks in between bars; setting `tickvals` to half of the interval range to the left to move the ticks off the center, and `ticktext` for the labels.

The reason it wasn't working before is because I had written my `tickvals` without using "" (I thought that, being numbers rather than text, I didn't need the inverted commas). This is how my code looks now, and it works:

```
chart %>% layout(title = '<b>Fund Distribution by Income</b>',
                 xaxis = list(
                   title = list(text='<b>Income</b>', standoff = 10),
                   ticks="outside", tickson="boundaries",
                   ticktext=list("0", "5,000", "10,000", "15,000", "20,000"), #label
                   tickvals=list("-2500", "2500", "7500", "12500", "17500")) #position
```